# Simple program crashes after using switch - C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

I just have written a program which suppose to return char which appears the most/least. Program work during the testing without switch statement, but when I added it start to crash. Can you have a look?

> Main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tools.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int c;
    while ( (c=getchar())!=EOF ){
        count[c]++;
    }
    switch (argv[1][1]) {
    case 'm': case 'M':
        mostOften(count);
        break;
    case 'l': case 'L':
        leastOften(count);
        break;
    default:
        mostOften(count);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Tools function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tools.h"

void mostOften(int *s) {
    int j;
    int max, cha;
    for(j=32; j<126; j++){
        if(s[j]>max) {
                max=s[j];
                cha=j;
        }
    }
    printf("char %c: %d times\n", cha, max);
}

void leastOften(int *s) {
    int j;
    int min=10000, cha;
    for(j=32; j<126; j++){
        if(s[j] && s[j]<=min) {
                min=s[j];
                cha=j;
        }
    }
    printf("char %c: %d times\n", cha, min);
}
```

Comment: add the `if (argc > 1 )` statement before the switch statement

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `max` uninitialized, thus, reading garbage:

```
int max, cha;
for(j=32; j<126; j++){
    if(s[j]>max) {
```

Also, you need to check if `argv[1][1]` exists before using it:

```
switch ((argc > 1 && argv[1][0]) ? argv[1][1] : 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help with crashes.

Comment: How are you launching your program in console?

Comment: With _Build and run_ option. I though I doesn't matter since there is default option.

Comment: Yes, it matters, `argv[1][1]` can be an out of bound access if you don't pass a param.